# Call public methods with parameters jQueryUI Widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am currently using jQuery UI widget factories and i am kind of struck in calling public methods with parameter.

This is what i have done.

```
//Widget 
$.widget('ui.MyWidget',{

public_method_without_params: function(){
  //do something;
}

public_method_with_params: function(word){
  //do something;
}
});
```

I'm trying to call public_method from outside. If it doesn't have a parameter i would have done either

(i) `$('#some-element').MyWidget("public_method_without_params")`

(or)

(ii) `$('#some-element').data("MyWidget").public_method_without_params();`

Is it possible to call the public_method_with_params similar to (i) mentioned above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently i have done this:

```
$('#some-element').data("MyWidget"). public_method_with_params(word);
```

and it works. Only problem is that i need to initialise "MyWidget" before this.

```
$('#some-element').MyWidget()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can. The syntax (I believe) is as follows:

```
$('#some-element').MyWidget("public_method_with_params", word);
```

Comment: No luck :( Currently i have used $('#some-element').data("MyWidget"). public_method_with_params(word);